# Try to describe my table but it said does not exist this table however it does

Tags: mysql

mysql> SHOW TABLES;

```
+-----------------------+
| Tables_in_‘maizi‘     |
+-----------------------+
| ‘cms_cate‘            |
| ‘course‘              |
| ‘user‘                |
| ’cms_news‘            |
+-----------------------+
```

4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DESCRIBE cms_news;

```
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table '‘maizi‘.cms_news' doesn't exist
```

Comment: try using backticks (`) around table name - not 100% this is the issue but may work

Comment: If it says it doesn't exist, then it can't find it. You may need to specify the database name and not just the table name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow you managed to create tables with wrong quotes attached.

There is a table in your DB called

```
’cms_news‘
```

but you search for

```
cms_news
```

Rename (or delete) all your tables and don't use `’` to escape names. Use backticks if you have to:

```
`cms_news`
```

But even backticks are only required for table names containing special characters or using reserved names in the DB.